# Angular access index outside *ngFor in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a list like this

```html
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let product of items.Products| slice 0:3 ; let i = index">
      {{ product?.ProductsDescription}}
   <li>
</ul>
```

All i want i to is, display a list of products, but i wan't to limit the exibition to only 3 products, and below, in another `<li></li>` display "And more {{ quantity-left-of-products }}"

#### Example:

I Have 6 products, so it would display:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- And more 3

Something like this:
[image: example image]

In my knowledge i would have to find a way to access the index property outside the ngFor.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want without accessing the index value outside the context.

Create a variable in TS to use it as a parameter in the slice pipe.

```
sliceValue = 3;

loadMore() {
   this.sliceValue = items.Products.length;
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of items.Products| slice 0:sliceValue ; let i = index">
        {{ product?.ProductsDescription}}
     <li>
    <li (click)="loadMore()" *ngIf="items.Products.length > sliceValue">And more {{items.Products.length - sliceValue}}</li>
</ul>
```

Use `*ngIf` for displaying the "And More" when necessary. When the user clicks on "And More" the `<li>` for "And More: hides and the rest of the list loads.

Comment: But i don't want to show the "And more" `<li>` when the user clicks it, i want it already there.

Comment: And there's no way of doing that only in the template?

Comment: @vaas I added the condition to hide "And More" when a user clicks on it. I guess you can't do it with template only.

Comment: Shouldn't the `ngIf` condition be: `items.Products.length > sliceValue`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes, this `items.Products.length > sliceValue`  also work. `items.Products.length !== sliceValue` these values are only equal when user sees full list which is aftter click event. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What if there are only 2 products? In your previous code, you would have seen "And more" but it should not be displayed.

Comment: @ConnorsFan That's right. I edited my answer with your suggestion. Thank you